# SSH Key and Known Hosts in Bitbucket Pipe

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

Recently I've been working with Bitbucket Pipes and I stumbled over something. Bitbucket Pipes don't seem to "inherit" the "SSH Key" and "Known Hosts" from the pipeline itself.

When I try to use SSH in the Bitbucket Pipe with the assumption that the Bitbucket Pipe inherits the "SSH Key" and "Known Hosts" from the pipeline it won't connect and give back an authentication error.

Is there a way to make use of the "SSH Key" and "Known Hosts" configured in the Bitbucket repository in the Bitbucket Pipe?

Answer (score 0):

By default, SSH-based Bitbucket Pipes ([ssh-run](https://bitbucket.org/product/features/pipelines/integrations?p=atlassian/ssh-run), [sftp-deploy](https://bitbucket.org/product/features/pipelines/integrations?p=atlassian/sftp-deploy), [rsync-deploy](https://bitbucket.org/product/features/pipelines/integrations?p=atlassian/rsync-deploy), etc.) provide behavior for using the configured SSH key and known hosts file.

You should [configure the SSH](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-ssh-keys-in-bitbucket-pipelines-847452940.html) private key and known_hosts in your Pipelines settings.

The following example shows how to execute SSH command on your remote server:

```
script:
  - pipe: atlassian/ssh-run:0.2.5
    variables:
      SSH_USER: 'ec2-user'
      SERVER: '127.0.0.1'
      COMMAND: 'echo $HOSTNAME'
```

If you're using another pipe, please, give more details to help you.